# SSRS Linked Report with allow multiple parameters

Tags: ssrs, reporting

I'm trying to create a linked report in SSRS to a report that has an "allow multiple values" parameter called CompanyCode.

If i call it with a single parameter it works fine, but I can't figure out how to call it with multiple.  Here's what I've tried:

CompanyCode1,CompanyCode2

and

CompanyCode1

CompanyCode2

and

'CompanyCode1','CompanyCode2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I' pretty sure you actually have to use a function for that.

From a quick google search, here are a few options:

```
=SPLIT(JOIN(Parameters!<your param name>.Value,","),",")
```

Or

```
=join(Parameters!<your param name>.Value,",")
```

One thing I remember vividly from my SSRS/ReportBuilder days was that when you're passing the value in from the main to the sub report (and it has multiple values), you pass the param in as "[@paramName]" and not "Parameters!.param.Value"

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I ended up using the split table UDF listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19935646/1764265 working like a charm

Comment: @safetyOtter: It's up to you which answer to accept (or whether to accept the only answer available at the time) but I must say that accepting an answer offering a very different approach from what you've ended up using is very misleading. Please consider posting a self-answer with an explanation of your own solution and accepting that instead.